# Weekend Celebrations or Weekend's Celebrations

Tags: grammar, possessives, attributive-nouns

Imagine a wedding invitation which ends with the following sentence:

> To round off the weekend celebrations, please join us for lunch.

Would it be more, less, or equally correct to say:

> To round off the weekend's celebrations, please join us for lunch.

Comment: Yes, the second form would be more or less equally correct :) . The first uses *weekend* as an adjective to *celebrations* while the second treats *celebrations* as something related to the *weekend*, which is used as a noun there.

Answer (score 1):

Either could be correct depending on your context.

In the first case, "weekend" could describe the type of celebration, like the theme for a party.  However, since the theme is a wedding, it could be used in the sense of having an implied "of", as in "weekend of celebrations", to refer to the scope of celebration time.

The second case refers to a specific celebration.  Making weekend possessive lets it take the place of the bride and groom's names as another way to refer to the event.

Comment: This looks like correct.